# Filter Posts By Tag

Tags: posts, customization, query-posts, filters, tags

I'm trying to filter my posts by category, then further by city. The only way I can think of filter by city is if the admin adds the city to the listed tags and then filtering from there via switch statement.

How can I filter posts by a certain tag?

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing?

My PHP knowledge is intermediate and my Wordpress knowledge is pretty basic. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

here you go,

The following returns all posts that belong to category 1 and are tagged "apples"

```
query_posts( 'cat=1&tag=apples' );
```

Add this inside the page before the loop

change '1' and 'apples' to whatever category and tag you want.

If you must use `query_posts()`, make sure you call `wp_reset_query()` after you're done.

look here for more info,

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts